# split string from txt file into a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
yes,54,good,less
no,55,good,less
no,26,good,less
```

i want to read it and represent it as a list of pairs. the first element in the pair is a triple(tuple) which contains the first three values, and the second element in the pair is the fourth element. With his code, I could just convert each line to a tuple and not to a pair.

```
import os
path=os.getcwd()
def gettest() -> list:
    with open(path+"\\health-train.txt")as f:
        lines = f.read()
        f = list(lines.split())
        a=[tuple(map(str,sub.split(','))) for sub in f]
    return a
```

i had this :

```
[('yes', '54', 'good', 'less'),
 ('no', '55', 'good', 'less'),
 ('no', '26', 'good', 'less')]
```

but i want to have this:

```
[(('yes', '54', 'good'), ('less',)),
 (('no', '55', 'good'), ('less',)),
 (('no', '26', 'good'), ('less',))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Said your previous tuples is stored by the variable `previous_result`. Here you go the code :D

```py
result = [(item[:3], (item[-1],)) for item in previous_result]

result
[(('yes', '54', 'good'), ('less',)), 
(('no', '55', 'good'), ('less',)), 
(('no', '26', 'good'), ('less',))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways.

For this replace the `f = list(lines.split())` and `a=[tuple(map(str,sub.split(','))) for sub in f]` lines with:

##### python ≥ 3.8:

```
a = [(tuple(t := sub.split(','))[:3], (t[3],)) for sub in lines.split()]
```

##### python 3

```
a = [(tuple(a), (b,)) for *a,b in map(lambda x: x.split(','), lines.split())]
```

##### all pythons

```
a = [(tuple(sub[:3]), (sub[3],)) for sub in map(lambda x: x.split(','), lines.split())]
```

output of a:

```
[(('yes', '54', 'good'), ('less')),
 (('no', '55', 'good'), ('less')),
 (('no', '26', 'good'), ('less'))]
```

Comment: Note OP wants second item in each list to be a tuple so you could adjust your solution to `tuple(t[3:]) ` rather than t[3] and similarly for sub[3].

Answer (score 0):

You could also use tuple unpacking and rearrangement, i.e.

```
s = """
yes,54,good,less
no,55,good,less
no,26,good,less
"""

lines = [x.split(',') for x in s.split()]  # split into lists of single words
print([((a,b,c),(d,)) for (a,b,c,d) in lines])
```

Output:

```
[(('yes', '54', 'good'), ('less',)),
 (('no', '55', 'good'), ('less',)),
 (('no', '26', 'good'), ('less',))]
```